# Button visibility on not-logged-in panel

Tags: bug, design, accessibility

It took me about a week to realise this was a dismissible popup—the button is extremely well hidden. Is this the right way to raise an accessibility issue?

[image: panel when not logged in]

The HTML is:

```
<div class="flex--item as-start md:ps-absolute t8 r8">
   <button class="s-btn s-btn__muted p8 js-dismiss">
      <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconClear" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
         <path d="M15 4.41 13.59 3 9 7.59 4.41 3 3 4.41 7.59 9 3 13.59 4.41 15 9 10.41 13.59 15 15 13.59 10.41 9 15 4.41Z">
         </path>
      </svg>
   </button>
</div>
```

The relevant CSS class, `s-btn`, can be found [here](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=85feea4d403d).

Comment: Should probably be replaced with a button next to the "Join Community" button. Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3L2O.png).